# How do I get my TranslateAnimation to show my LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I've been working on a single screen android application, but I'm having trouble getting my TranslateAnimation method to function properly. I'm looking for the view group to slide from off app to where it's designed to finish.

Can you guys take a gander and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Java Activity:

```
public class AboutProcess extends AppCompatActivity {

Button myButton;
View myView;
boolean isUp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_process);

    myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
    myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

    //set as invisible
    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    isUp = false;
}
public void slideUp(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            view.getHeight(),   // fromYDelta
            0);                // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(50);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
}

// slide the view from its current position to below itself
public void slideDown(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            0,                 // fromYDelta
            view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(50);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
}

public void onSlideViewButtonClick(View view) {
    if (isUp) {
        slideDown(myView);
        myButton.setText("SHOW LINKS");
    } else {
        slideUp(myView);
        myButton.setText("HIDE LINKS");
    }
    isUp = !isUp;
}
```

}

And here is the XML for the button click and the viewgroup that I'm trying to have animate onto the screen. Within the LinearLayout are a set of four images.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lasvegas"
    android:text="SHOW LINKS"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="@dimen/med_font"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding50"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:onClick="buttonFB"
        android:src="@drawable/white_fb"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding15"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:id="@+id/youtube"
        android:onClick="buttonTube"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tube"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding15"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:id="@+id/tweet"
        android:onClick="buttonTweet"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tweet"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding15"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:id="@+id/www"
        android:onClick="buttonWWW"
        android:src="@drawable/white_www"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding15"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I implement this code on my device, the button shows and is 'clickable' but the view group is not on my screen, nor can I find it at any point. Any ideas of what I'm missing (or how to program the animation differently for this concept)?